# How to get volume keycode value when I push volume up / down from Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth

When I push `Volume up/down` from `Bluetooth` headset, I want to capture `KeyCode` of `VolumeKey`.

I can get `KeyCode` of `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY`, `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE`, `KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT` and `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS`.

But I just can not get `KeyCode` of volume.

Do you have any solution?

If you have it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think key events of different Bluetooth headsets vary and configurable.

But in general, try capture `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP` and `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN`.

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the key events and then filter them accordingly to your need!

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
        ...
        return true;
    }else if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)){
        ...
        return true;
    }else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```